# Angular 2 Route 3.0.0.beta-2 : How to async routes?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 2 app with Webpack which uses the latest Angular Router 3.0.0.beta-2.

Can someone please help to know, how to specify async routes ?

Thanks in advance.